# Framework for Asynchronous communication

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

My windows Phone 8 app asynchronously connects to a WCF service hosted on remote server to perform CRUD operations. Currenlty all the trasactions are manually taken care in the code like handling all kinds of exceptions, losing connectivity during operations, or any exceptions returned from code. Just wanted to know is there any framework available that can be used to handle these common scenarios so that development time can be reduced.

Comment: @Duncan Thanks for the quick response. I see that it is a commercial solution and we have to pay for it .I would like to know if there are any equivalent opensource versions available.

Comment: How about http://signalr.net/ ?

Comment: You could migrate to the Rx framework.  It has some pretty groovy retry and error handling http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 0):

> You can use UnhandledExceptionEventHandler

using System;

public class Sample
{

public static void Example()

{

```
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

    try
    {
        throw new Exception("First Handled Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Catch clause caught : " + e.Message);
    }

    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Second Handled Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Catch clause caught : " + e.Message);
        // throw;
        // throw new Exception("Re-throw second exception", e);
    }

    // throw new Exception("Un-Handled Exception");
}

static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: {0}", e.Message);
}

public static void Main()
{
    Example();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could migrate to *Reactive Extensions* (Rx).

MSDN:

> Rx .NET is a managed library that provides APIs for writing reactive, push-based apps. Reactive apps are driven by their environment. In the reactive model, data streams, asynchronous requests, and events are represented as observable sequences. The app can subscribe to these observable sequences to receive asynchronous messages as new data arrives. Reactive Extensions allows the app to compose these sequences using query operators. [More...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431792(v=vs.105).aspx)

It has some pretty groovy retry and error handling.

```
source.Retry(3).Catch(...)
```

The good news it is also available for Windows Phone 8.1

### More

- [Reactive extensions for .NET (Rx .NET) for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431792(v=vs.105).aspx)
- [Advanced error handling](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html)